# Embedded struct

Tags: go

Is it possible to inherit methods of a type without using embedded structs?

The first snippet of code is working code that embeds the `Property` struct in `Node` and I'm able to call `node.GetString` that's a method on `Properties`.  The thing I don't like about this is when I initialize `Node` I have(?) to initialize the `Properties` struct within it.  Is there a way around this?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Properties map[string]interface{}

func (p Properties) GetString(key string) string {
    return p[key].(string)
}

type Nodes map[string]*Node

type Node struct {
    *Properties
}

func main() {
    allNodes := Nodes{"1": &Node{&Properties{"test": "foo"}}} // :'(
    singleNode := allNodes["1"]
    fmt.Println(singleNode.GetString("test"))
}
```

Ultimately, I would like to do something like the following.  Where `Node` is of type `Properties` and initializing does not require initializing a `Property` struct too.  The following code doesn't work but may be clear what my goal is.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Properties map[string]interface{}

func (p Properties) GetString(key string) string {
    return p[key].(string)
}

type Nodes map[string]*Node

type Node Properties

func main() {
    allNodes := Nodes{"1": &Node{"test": "foo"}} // :)
    singleNode := allNodes["1"]
    fmt.Println(singleNode.GetString("test")) // :D
}
```

I'll be adding more structs that will use `Properties`'s methods which is why I'm asking.  If I only had `Node`, I would just have methods for `Node` and be done.  But because I'll have more than `Node` I find it kind of redundant to add the same methods to all the structs that embed `Properties`

I guess more to the exact problem, I want to use `Properties` methods from `Node` without having to initialize `Properties`.

Comment: Sounds to me like you could perhaps just write functions that accept an instance of a `Properties` object and operate on it, rather than attaching them to it. This is how embedding in Go works though ... so I'm not sure theres a way around that. Composition, not inheritance.

Comment: Embedding is called embedding for a reason ;) All Properties fields get embedded into Node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're running into an idiosyncrasy of Go here. Embedding is the only way in which methods of one struct can get "promoted" to appear to exist on another struct. While it feels intuitive that `type Node Properties` should expose the `Properties` methods on `Node`, that effect of that syntax is for `Node` to take on the memory layout of `Properties` but not any of its methods.

It doesn't explain why this design choice was made but the [Go Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) is at least specific if dry. If you read it exactly as it appears, with no interpretation, it is very accurate:

> The method set of an interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type T consists of all methods declared
>   with receiver type T

`GetString` has a receiver of type `Properties` not `Node`, seriously, interpret the spec like you're an accountant with no imagination. With that said:

> Further rules apply to structs containing anonymous fields, as described in the section on struct types.
>
> ...
>
> A field or method f of an anonymous field in a struct x is called promoted if x.f is a legal selector that denotes that field or method f.
>
> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they
>   cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.
>
> Given a struct type S and a type named T, promoted methods are
>   included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - If S contains an anonymous field T, the method sets of S and *S both
>     include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also
>     includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
> - If S contains an anonymous
>     field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods
>     with receiver T or *T.

That line about composite literals is this thing that forces you to declare `Properties` inside every `Node` you create.

p.s. Hi Jeff!

Comment: Hi David! I would be interested to hear why that design choice was made.  It's probably in the spec somewhere just deep between the lines. Hope all is well with you.

Comment: @Jeff: The design choice here is that Go doesn't have inheritance, and doesn't have method overloading. Embedding is just a convenient method for automatic delegation, with specific rules about how the selector can promote fields and methods (you can always call them directly too), nothing is "inherited".

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your last question is simply **No**.

There is a big difference between type declaration and embedding in [golang](/questions/tagged/golang), you can make your last example working by manually make a type conversion between `Node` and `Properties`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Properties map[string]interface{}

func (p Properties) GetString(key string) string {
    return p[key].(string)
}

type Nodes map[string]*Node

type Node Properties

func main() {
    allNodes := Nodes{"1": &Node{"test": "foo"}} // :)
    singleNode := allNodes["1"]
    fmt.Println(Properties(*singleNode).GetString("test")) // :D
}
```

But it's clearly that is not what you want, you want a struct embedding with a syntax of type aliasing, which is not possible in [golang](/questions/tagged/golang), I think that you should stuck with the your first approach and ignore the the fact the code is redundant and ugly .