# Calling methods from derived type in Go

Tags: go, types

I have two files, generic_handler.go, which essentially looks like this:

```
type Handler struct{
    fields map[string]interface{}
}

func (handler *Handler) addField(key string, value interface{}){ some code }
```

And stat_handler.go:

```
type StatHandler Handler
```

When I try to call (from within the stat_handler.go file) the method like this, I get an error:

```
//inside some function
stathandler.addField("some field", "some value")
```

It errors out with `type StatHandler has no field or method addField`. This is the same even if I export `addField` by making it `AddField`. Both of these files reside in the same package.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079466/golang-embedded-struct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Go you'd typically do this through composition:

```
type StatHandler struct {
    Handler  // Anonymous member of type Handler
}

// ...Later on
var stathandler StatHandler
stathandler.addField("some field", "some value")
```

Comment: Ahh! I knew it was something obvious... I remember reading about this in the Go documentation but I must've not understood it completely. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

A declared method belongs to a specific type. The [`type`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) keyword creates a *new* type which does not "inherit" methods of the type you used in the type specification.

The method `addField()` you declared belongs to `Handler`, the type `StatHandler` does not have any methods because you haven't specified any methods with that as the receiver type.

If you have a variable of type `StatHandler` and if you want to call the `addField()` method, you need to have a value of type `*Handler`. You may obtain such a value by using a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), e.g.:

```
s := StatHandler{}
(*Handler)(&s).addField("somekey", "someval")
```

Note that since `addField()` has pointer receiver, a pointer is required (hence the use of `&` address operator), but then the `*StatHandler` can only be converted to `*Handler`.

If you would have an `*StatHandler` pointer in the first place:

```
sp := &StatHandler{}
(*Handler)(sp).addField("somekey", "someval")
```

Since new types do not "inherit" methods of the underlying type, you should consider [*embedding*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) to achieve what you want, because methods and fields of an embedded type are *promoted* to the embedder type:

```
type StatHandler struct {
    Handler // Embed Handler, so addField() method will be promoted
}

s2 := StatHandler2{}
s2.addField("somekey", "someval")
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uoov_FES1w).

The exact definition of what methods a type has is covered in the spec: [Method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets).

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that in Go in order to access a method from another package you need to export it, meaning that you have to capitalize the first letter of the method.

```
type Handler struct{
    fields map[string]interface{}
}

func (handler *Handler) AddField(key string, value interface{}){ some code }
```

Then if your package is named as `stathandler` you can access the `AddField` method as:

```
stathandler.AddField("some field", "some value")
```

Comment: Not to be rude, but you didn't read the question. I already tried exporting it, and the same exact error occurs. They are in the same package.