# Understanding struct embedding

Tags: go, methods, struct

Can someone explain me why this code  prints 1 and not 2?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type S1 struct{
    f1 string
}

type S2 struct{
    S1
    f2 string
}   

func (s *S1) Say(){
    fmt.Println("1")
}   

func (s *S2) Say(){
    fmt.Println("2")
}       

type S3 S2

func main() {
    var s3 S3
    s3.Say()
}
```

(Runnable at: https://play.golang.org/p/_cjNxBKgSf)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34083564/4029014).

Specifically, from [the Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) we have **Method Sets:**

> **Method sets**
>
> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an
>   interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type T
>   consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. The method set
>   of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods
>   declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method
>   set of T). Further rules apply to structs containing embedded fields,
>   as described in the section on struct types. Any other type has an
>   empty method set. In a method set, each method must have a unique
>   non-blank method name.

Then Struct typess:

> **Struct types**
>
> A struct is a sequence of named elements, called fields, each of which
>   has a name and a type. Field names may be specified explicitly
>   (IdentifierList) or implicitly (EmbeddedField). Within a struct,
>   non-blank field names must be unique.

Then this:

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an *embedded field.*

Finally, this:

> A field or method f of an embedded field in a struct x is called
>   *promoted* if `x.f` is a legal selector that denotes that field or method `f`.
>
> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they
>   cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.
>
> Given a struct type S and a type named T, promoted methods are
>   included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> ```
> If S contains an embedded field T, the method sets of S and *S 
> both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S
> also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
>
> If S contains an embedded field *T, the method sets of S and *S 
> both include promoted methods with receiver T or *T.
> ```

How does all that combine?

You have

```
type S2 struct{
    S1
    f2 string
}
```

which makes S1 an embedded field, and makes S1.Say visible.

Then you have:

```
type S3 S2
```

Which makes S3 have the same memory layout and fields as S2, but *does not* create a type equivalence. This is not saying that S3 "is a" S2, but rather that S3 **is not** the same as S2, but they do have the same layout.

That layout includes embedded fields, which happens to bring S1.Say into the equation.

Put another way, type S2 has an underlying type of:

```
struct { S1; f2 string }
```

and a method called Say.

Type S3 has an *identical* underlying type of:

```
struct { S1; f2 string }
```

But S3 and S2 are not the same, and so S3 does not "inherit" any methods from S2. Instead, S3 inherits only the fields/methods from its underlying type, which are f2, and S1.* (including "Say").

Comment: Ok. Think i start understanding... That's why https://play.golang.org/p/QM_ppjBTcz prints 1,2.

Comment: So when i create a new type for a present one and that type has embedded structs, only the methods of the embedded structs will be promoted, but not the once from the present type itself. Why? What's the purpose of this? Just the way go implemnts it or is this good for some reason?

Comment: I ran into this, when trying to create a new helper method for an struct definied in an other package.I have (db)models, that have embedded structs for relations (sqlx). All models have an Insert method. To be able to create the method (in another package than models) i had to create a new type, but calling Insert called the method of the embedded struct. 
Even if i understand now, why this happens i'd like to understand why google implemented it this way.

Comment: Couldn't this lead to a realy mess, if you create new types of structs defined in external librarys? You have to know, if the struct embedds other structs, if not, you can't even say what methods will be called.
I fixed this by creating a function right now, and for 1.9 i could use type aliases but still, why is it implemented like this?

Comment: Keep in mind that there are two "sources" for this. First, the embedded fields: I don't know why this is a thing - that is, I don't know why it's possible to include anonymous sub-structures. But, once that decision was made, it's just a matter of consistency- any structure that includes an embedded S1 as a child struct will automatically get the fields and methods, because that's how it is. So S3 gets S1.Say that way. I believe that the decision to not share methods between aliased types is part of emphasizing the separate-ness of the types. That's the second source: so, no S2.Say.

Answer (score 2):

Its important to know, that when you create another name for a type, you *can not* use the types interchangeably. They are *two distinct types* for Go's typesystem, even though they share the same underlying representation.

You have two distinct types, `S2` and `S3`. `S2` has a function `Say`, `S3` however *has not*. But since `S3` has the same underlying struct as `S2`, it *does* have a `S1` embedded, which *does* have a function `Say`, so thats what gets called.